# How to know how many conditions in WHERE statement have met its criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Lets say we have the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT ID
FROM table1
WHERE P1 = P1 AND (P2 = X OR P3 = Y OR P4 = Z)
```

This statement should return a result if at least two conditions in parentheses have met its criteria, but I don't know how to write a statement that gives this kind of result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's `P1 = P1` in your example good for as it will always evaluate to true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions for each of the conditions that return `1` or `0` and add them:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table1 
WHERE P1 = P1 
  AND CASE WHEN P2 = X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN P3 = Y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN P4 = Z THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 2
```

This is scalable for more conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, we can just expand your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM table1
WHERE P1 = P1 AND (
                  P2 = X AND P3 = Y OR
                  P2 = X AND P4 = Z OR
                  P3 = Y and P4 = Z);
```

Depending on your data and the logic behind it, it might be possible to simplify the above even further.

Comment: While your approach works for this discussion use case, it generalizes poorly as it leads to combinatorial explosion. For example, "I want 7 of 15 predicates to be true"